# Maven NAR Dependency - Could not resolve dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

My Dependencie is built as a `nar`(which contains java files and a jni wrapper)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jni</groupId>
        <artifactId>jni</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

now If I do

```
mvn clean package
```

it says `Could not resolve dependencies for project java:javatest:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jni:jni:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

the problem is, that in a project with nar-Packaging the output is named `.nar` instead of `.jar` so if I copy the `jni.nar` in my local repository(`~/.m2/repository/jni/jni`) and name it `jni.jar` it works fine.

Any Idea how I could solve that without manually renaming the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to tell Maven your dependency type is different:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jni</groupId>
        <artifactId>jni</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>nar</type>
</dependency>
```

NOTE: I'm guessing the type is "nar" here. Check the POM of the dependency to see what the actual type is.

Comment: The type is not necessarily related to the extension or the packaging. It is indeed `nar` here, [but because the plugin decided for that](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/blob/nar-maven-plugin-3.5.1/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml#L112-L115).

Comment: doesn't work either, In my understanding I would use that, If my project is also a NAR project which needs the shared library as a dependency?

Comment: @Tunaki Indeed! That's why I wrote I'm only guessing it's "nar".

Comment: @user2071938 what "doesn't work" means? Are you getting the same error? Adding the type should correctly identify the artifact - which is what your original issue was. Note that how do you use that artifact is different story.

Comment: got it! I need to add the `nar-maven-plugin` as well to use `nar`-dependencies